# apache tomcat issue - 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Im trying to access login page of my project but getting 404 error.

Link : http://21.176.504.76:8081/test-online

tomcat startup page is appearing properly so tomcat is installed succesfully

I have not added my project to the tomcat server. Im accessing the login page by the env.properties file.
env.properties file includes the following

server=http://21.176.504.76:8081

server.local=${server}

contextpath=/test-online

Here 21.176.504.76 is my ip address

Below is the logs appearing in the console while starting the tomcat server.

01 Apr 2016 8:59:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
01 Apr 2016 8:59:05 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

01 Apr 2016 8:59:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1616 ms

01 Apr 2016 8:59:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
01 Apr 2016 8:59:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.45

01 Apr 2016 8:59:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01 Apr 2016 8:59:16 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:16 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:16 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:16 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.
01 Apr 2016 8:59:19 AM absa.sdfc.icd.configuration.ConfigurationManager getConfiguration
WARNING: Configuration is null. Configuration might not have been loaded.

01 Apr 2016 8:59:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Throwable occurred: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'portal_userSessionContextFilter' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'portal_userSessionResolverFactory' while setting bean property 'userSessionResolverFactory';
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'portal_userSessionResolverFactory' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'portal_service_commandService' while setting bean property 'commandService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'portal_service_commandService' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'portal_command_commandsCache' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'portal_command_commandsCache' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deactivate transaction synchronization - not active

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'portal_userSessionResolverFactory' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'portal_service_commandService' while setting bean property 'commandService';
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'portal_service_commandService' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'portal_command_commandsCache' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Error creating bean with name 'portal_command_commandsCache' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed;
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deactivate transaction synchronization - not active
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 33 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Error creating bean with name 'portal_service_commandService' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'portal_command_commandsCache' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'portal_command_commandsCache' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Cannot deactivate transaction synchronization - not active
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 46 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Error creating bean with name 'portal_command_commandsCache' defined in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot deactivate transaction synchronization - not active
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 61 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot deactivate transaction synchronization - not active

```
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.clearSynchronization(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:274)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.clear(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:412)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:905)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:774)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:719)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:329)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy11.getLastCommandId(Unknown Source)
at com.backbase.portal.personalization.storage.cache.CommandsCache.updateIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
... 71 more
```

01 Apr 2016 8:59:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

01 Apr 2016 8:59:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start

SEVERE: Context [/test-online] startup failed due to previous errors

01 Apr 2016 8:59:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

01 Apr 2016 8:59:23 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start

INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

01 Apr 2016 8:59:23 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init

INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009

01 Apr 2016 8:59:23 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start

INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/214  config=null

01 Apr 2016 8:59:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 17779 ms

Answer (score 0):

spring  can not  find this type which is  called  portal_command_commandsCache。.
So  you should check your ApplicationContext.xml, and make sure that there is a right name or right type for it. When tomcat starts, spring will inject the bean to the type.  When it doesn't find the bean ,it will throw this exception.

Comment: I cant find portal_command_commandsCache. Also i dont have ApplicationContext.xml. I checked and i have ApplicationConfig.java and Application.xml. I have backbase portal jars

Comment: Do you have  the bean which is called 'portal_command_commandsCache'   in class path resource [backbase-portal-storage-service.xml].  Because 'portal_service_commandService'  should  references  it. And the exception msg prints it can't find it.